# Android ClassCastException android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, radio-group

I'm new to android and making an application in which i need to use spinners and radio group button values for mathematical calculation .I have tried different ways and also Google this issue but didn't succeed . Please some  one help me in this. Thanks.

**Logcat Error: ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner**

Here is my code:

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gender"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="Height"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rmale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rfemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female" />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_feet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gender" 
    android:entries="@array/feet_values"
    android:prompt="@string/feet" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_inch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/result"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sp_feet"
    android:entries="@array/inch_values"
    android:prompt="@string/inch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Calculate" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.wc;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private RadioGroup radiogendergroup;
 private RadioButton radiogenderbutton;
 private Spinner feet;
 private Spinner inch;
 private TextView res;
 private Button calculate;

 double cal;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radiogendergroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogender);
    feet= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_feet);
    inch= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_inch);

    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    res= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             int selectedId = radiogendergroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
             radiogenderbutton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
             String selectedValue = radiogenderbutton.getText().toString();
             double f = Double.parseDouble(feet.getSelectedItem().toString());
             double i = Double.parseDouble(inch.getSelectedItem().toString());

             if(selectedValue=="Male" && f==5){

                 cal= 50 + 2.3*i;
                    String result = new Double(cal).toString();
                    res.setText(result);
             }

             if(selectedValue=="Male" && f==6){

                 cal= 77.6 + 2.3*i;
                    String result = new Double(cal).toString();
                    res.setText(result);
             }
             if(selectedValue=="Female" && f==5){

                 cal= 45.5 + 2.3*i;
                    String result = new Double(cal).toString();
                    res.setText(result);
             }               
         }
       });
}
```

}

LogCat Error after modification:

```
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wc/com.example.wc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at com.example.wc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 07-08 12:05:09.171: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your question is not related to your Error **Logcat Error: Value No of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Logcat Error: Value No of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

It seems that your issue in comparison,So use `.equals()` instead of `==` for **String** comparison
i.e. in your code,change

```
selectedValue=="Male"
```

to

```
selectedValue.equals("Male")
```

and

```
selectedValue=="Female"
```

to

```
selectedValue.equals("Female")
```

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

For more info see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

**Edit**

Please clean your project because it may be possible that you had assign an id to `TextView`, R.java builds, but later you assign the same name to `Spinner` without building R.java.

As R.java keeps reference of all controls, so at first time you assign to Textview so R.java consider that this id is a Textview but now you assigned it to Spinner and R.java is totally unaware until you clean and build .

Comment: now its giving an Logcat error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.textview cannot be cast to android.widget.spinner and unfortunately application has stopped

Comment: @Zohaib in which line,please post logcat exception.

Comment: @Zohaib what is line 30 in main activity.

Comment: line 30: inch= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_inch);

Comment: @Zohaib try to clear your project and Re-run,See edited answer.

Comment: @Zohaib Happy to help,enjoy coding.